# Read file from STDIN and write to STDOUT

Tags: perl, file

I want to read html files entered from STDIN perform some function and then write another html file to STDOUT. My problem is I have to give file in the stated manner. I have tried many things but nothing is working good. Nothing is getting printed

my command line prompt

```
perl universe.pl<sun.html>galaxy.html
```

my code -

```
open(my $in, "<&STDIN")     or die "Can't dup STDIN: $!";
open(my $out, ">&STDOUT")     or die "Can't dup STDOUT: $!";

my @lines = <$in>;
foreach(@lines) {
   push(@newlines,$_);
   say "Lines pushing:", $_;
}
```

Comment: You almost have to try hard to fail on that; reading from standard input is very simple, and writing to standard output is very simple.  So, as Paul said, you need to show what you are trying, because you must be over-thinking.  Hint: the words STDIN and STDOUT won't appear in your script.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to open STDIN or STDOUT; they're always ready opened.

You don't need to slurp the whole file into memory as you do with:

```
my @lines = <$in>;
```

You never use `$out` which should be indicative of a problem.

```
while (<>)
{
    print mapping_func($_);
}
```

where `mapping_func()` is your function that does the relevant transform on its input string and returns the mapped result:

```
sub mapping_func
{
    my($string) = @_;
    $string =~ s/html/HTML/gi;
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: @user2907995: Why not? What part of your problem have I not addressed? It reads from standard input, as required; it writes to standard output, as required; it invokes a function to process the line that was read, which was what you said you needed to do. Some of your comments asked about how to handle multiple files; this code will actually work if invoked as `perl universe.pl file1.html file2.html file3.html > output.html`, writing all the output to the single file. If you want to overwrite the original files, then `perl -i.bak universe.pl file1.html file2.html file3.html` will do each file.

Answer (score 1):

Using the magic diamond operator `<>`, you will able to do what you asked. But please to provide some more search efforts next time.

```
use strict; use warnings;

while (my $line = <>) {
   # do something with $line
}
```

Last but not least; if you have to parse HTML the good way, have a look to [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath) or just [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder)

Comment: Note that this answer was provided before the code was added to the question.

Comment: this is good if i give only one input file
like - perl universe.pl<sun.html

Comment: @user2907995: You can only give one input file with the command notation that you are not allowed to change.

Comment: This is what you asked : `perl universe.pl<sun.html>galaxy.html`

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem with a script which was run from inside another Perl script.

The solution was to set $| in the second script (the one which executes the script which reads from STDIN).

Answer (score -2):

Below is my own effort:

```
#!/bin/perl
while (<>)
    {
        print $_;
    }
```

I like to start from the simplest possible example before I undertake more complex tasks.

Being barely an intermediate-level perl programmer, I am not sure how critical these statements are and what they are for:

use strict;
use warnings;

... so I temporarily omitted them from the start of my script and it still worked.